# Remove white spaces in subplots matplolib

Tags: python, matplotlib, geopandas, python-xarray

I try to plot the subplots as shown below. It works okay but it still have some white spaces at the end of figure. Is it possible remove white spaces. Any help would be very great.

Here is the code and simulated data.

```
import numpy as np 
import xarray as xr 
import geopandas as gpd 
import requests

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
# Define a function to convert string coordinates into float 
def data_extract(link):
    text = requests.get(link).text.split(",")
    return np.array([float(i) for i in text if i])
# Get longitude and latitude
y = data_extract("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tuyenhavan/test/main/latitude.txt")
x = data_extract("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tuyenhavan/test/main/longtitude.txt")
# Make some random data covering the area with above coordinates
random_data = np.random.randint(0, 3, (22, 937, 399))
# Wrap them into Xarray DataArray
data = xr.DataArray(random_data, dims=("band", "y", "x"), coords={
    "band": np.arange(len(random_data)),
    "y": y,
    "x": x
})
# Get the study area 
aoi = gpd.read_file("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tuyenhavan/test/main/area.geojson")
# Visualize the result 
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=8, figsize=(12,16), sharex=True, sharey=True)

fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=-0.55)

cmap="Spectral"
# fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.2, hspace=0.25)
for i, ax in enumerate(axes.flatten()):
    if i<len(data):
        tem = data[i]
        tem=tem.rio.write_crs(aoi.crs)
        plot = tem.plot(ax=ax, cmap=cmap, add_colorbar=False, vmin=1, vmax=3)
        aoi.plot(ax=ax, color="None", edgecolor="black", linewidth=0.5)
        ax.set_title(f"{1+i}")
        ax.set_ylabel("")
        ax.set_xlabel("")
        ax.set_ylabel("")
        ax.set_xlabel("")

    else:
        ax.axis("off")
```

[image]

Comment: It looks like that in order not to stretch the shapes.  You can either make the figure narrower (e.g. `plt.subplots(...., figsize=(7,15))`) or use more columns (e.g. `plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=10, ...)` and leave some subplots empty).

Comment: Thanks @JohanC. It can work actually, but it reduced the figure (figure height is too large compared to its width). I hope to keep the figure width relative to figure height. We can see it clearly when pasting the figure on powerpoint.

Comment: So, what's your suggestion? It is a physical problem.  Just try to move 25 cutouts of these rectangles onto a piece of paper.  Maybe `plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=13, ...)` fits your purpose?

Comment: Thank you. But it does not work properly. I tried different ways, but it still has white space problems.

Comment: Thanks JohanC. I hope someone encountered the same problem and had the solution.

Comment: If you pass `bbox_inches="tight"` when you save then that will remove white space from around the edges.

Comment: Thanks RuthC. But still doesn't work.